# Use element id instead of his location during CodedUi Test

Tags: web-applications, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I'm trying to make some CodedUI Test of my client web using my webapp and wondering why the generate code use X/Y location instead of Id of element ? 
In case i make a successfull test, if i move a button of his current location the test will fail.
Is it possible to change that behavior ? Force the Test Builder to work with id instead of location ? (he did that for my winform application but not the website)

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Toti,Can you please provide sample code? If I'm understanding correctly, then you are asking if x, y location generated in an event like following example code snippet can be removed: Mouse.Click(uIDeltaPlaceHolderMainPane, new Point(153, 94)); If this is the case, then you can remove the location (x, y) like: Mouse.Click(uIDeltaPlaceHolderMainPane) and the code still works. Please give sample of your code, then it will be easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

The generated code does not use x,y coordinates **of** the control, they are the coordinates **within** (or **relative to**) the control.

Commonly the code includes statements such as:

```
Mouse.Click(uIControl, new Point(25, 12));
```

One purpose of the x,y part is for buttons that also have a drop down menu. (For example, the SAVE-AS button in some programs has a little triangle that, when clicked, provides a choice of format for the saved file.) The x,y coordinate allows Coded UI to click on the main button or open the menu. Another use can be seen with programs such as Microsoft Paint where the coordinate refers to a place within the drawing area. (To understand this, try recording the actions of making a simple drawing with Microsoft Paint and looking at the generated code.)

In most cases the x,y coordinates can safely be removed, so the statement above can be simplified to:

```
Mouse.Click(uIControl);
```

See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mathew_aniyan/2012/03/16/faq-why-are-we-using-coordinate-based-actions-in-coded-ui-test/) for a fuller explanation.